# Is it possible to use generator functions in browser with Babel-transpiled code?

Tags: javascript, generator, babeljs

How can I use ES2015 generator functions in code transpiled via Babel which runs in the browser?

Setting `plugins: ['transform-runtime']` seems to work for node environments, not for browser ones.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. [tag:babel] is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"seems to work for node environments, not for browser ones."*?

Comment: It uses `require` to get the polyfill in.

Comment: Are you not using modules for the rest of your app? If you are not converting to a module system with browser support, you need to use a module bundler, e.g. browserify.

Comment: I am not and wouldn't want to add one for now. Is there any other way to get generators working using Babel? I keep finding a babel polyfil when I search for this, but am unsure if this is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Here's whay I mean: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/